# How to abort a stuck command in ubuntu server?

Tags: server, command-line

I know there is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, but sometimes that doesn't work. In Ubuntu desktop I can just close the terminal window and open a new one when this happens, but how would this be solved using the CLI in Ubuntu server (without restarting the box)?

Comment: see also [How to bind a key to sigkill in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/339887/4418)

Comment: `Enter ↵`, `~`, `.` is what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43189095/470749

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will send `SIGINT` to the application. The application can configure a handler for this signal or it can ignore the signal. By default there is no handler and `SIGINT` will kill the application.

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> which will send `SIGQUIT`. This will also generate a core dump if the core limit is not zero.

You can suspend the process and return to shell with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, this will [stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_state#Ready_or_waiting) the execution of the process and return to the shell prompt. The process will be in memory and it will be available as a job in the current shell. You can then use `kill -SIGNAL %%` or `kill -SIGNAL %<job_ID>` to send a signal to that job. E.g. to kill the last job use `kill -9 %%`

If none of them are working you can always send `SIGTERM`, then, as last resort, `SIGKILL` which will terminate any process. This signal as any other signals must be sent as the same user as the process you are trying to stop or as root. To send `SIGKILL` to process, first find the process with `ps aux` or `ps -edf`, then run `kill -SIGKILL <process_ID>`, where the `<process_ID>` is the `PID` column in `ps` output.

The signals can not be delivered if the process is in an uninterruptible call. Uninterruptible calls are kernel functions that can not be stopped and usually happen because of a bad driver (e.g. a driver that is not [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)). A process that is in [uninterruptible sleep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_sleep#Uninterruptible_sleep) can not be stopped until the call gets completed or the server is rebooted. Those signals will be held in the pending (Pnd) signals list. The pending signals for a process can be show with this [small script](https://github.com/mircea-vutcovici/scripts/blob/master/show-signal-queues-for-process.sh) that is just geting them from `/proc/<PID>/status`.

If a process becomes a [zombie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process), it will not use any resources only taking space in the process table. A zombie process can not receive signals.

The list of signals for the current architecture can be found with `kill -l`

See the man pages of `kill`, `ps` and `bash`. To see a man page use something like: `man ps`

Answer (score 3):

If you have full console access, you can do <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1..12</kbd> and get a new console.

From there, you can do a process listing like follows:

```
ps aux | grep <process-name>
```

Then do a `kill` on the process ID:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

If you don't have full console access, just open another terminal window (perhaps via PuTTY or similar), and do the above process listing and kill steps.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl C sends a SIGINT to your running process. 
If you don't want to open another console you can send a SIGQUIT with Ctrl \. This will address most day to day hung apps that the SIGINT does not.

I've personally wanted a way to send a SIGKILL with a shortcut but I'm not aware of a way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I consider `pgrep` and `pkill` to be easier to use than `kill` with an explicit process ID.

Also, instead of starting with signal 9 (SIGKILL), consider starting with the default SIGTERM (15).   This will give the process a chance to terminate gracefully (if it can). 
`pkill -15 thing` and `pkill thing` should be equivalent.

Here's how that would work.  Let's say that ntpd is hung.

What are the processes?  (You can skip to pkill if you believe you won't have false positives).

```
$ pgrep -fl ntp
1034 /usr/sbin/ntpd
1037 /usr/sbin/ntpd
```

Kill the processes:

```
$ pkill ntpd
```

Use `pgrep` again to see if it was successful.

If not, eventually move to `pkill -9`.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**

<kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> worked for me (where <kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>z</kbd> didn't work)

**Optional reading**

I usually follow the steps below when Ubuntu 16.04 freezes in my Lenovo Thinkpad E470.

1. Go to no-gui mode (<kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).
2. Use `top` command to see which process has high CPU usage (above 50% or so). Note the PID of the process.
3. Come out of `top` command (press <kbd>q</kbd>).
4. [Only if you know `kill` command] Kill the process using `kill -9 <process ID you noted down>`.
5. Go back to UI mode (<kbd>Cntrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>)

Answer (score 1):

You would switch to a new terminal, find the PID of the stuck process (using `ps`), then use `kill` to kill the process. I would first use `kill (PID)`. If that doesn't work, I would use `kill -9 (PID)`. If that doesn't stop the process the machine needs to be rebooted.